# Unable to get Result from the query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to find the list of providers who have the skills matching a desired value (in this case Delivery Management).

Query 1: To get the skills Ids I am using the below query

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_skills WHERE skill_name LIKE '%Delivery Management%'
```

Returns two ids `202,395`
Skills Ids = `202,395`

Query 2: To search the list of users with the matching skills

```
SELECT *, (6371 * acos (
        cos ( radians('28.4594965') )
        * cos( radians( latitude ) )
        * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('77.0266383') )
        + sin ( radians('28.4594965') )
        * sin( radians( latitude )
))) AS distance
FROM tbl_serviceprovider
WHERE skills IN(202,395)
ORDER BY distance;
```

But it is returning no results. In the `tbl_serviceprovider` table skills are stored as comma separated lists like `1,2,3`

Provider Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_serviceprovider` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `profession` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `dob` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `longitude` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `profile_pic` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `attachedDocument` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `education` text NOT NULL,
  `otherEducation` text NOT NULL,
  `aadharNumber` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `skills` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `briefDescription` text NOT NULL,
  `userAvailable` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `timeFrom` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `timeTo` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
(108, 'Amit Kaushik', 111, 'Male', '', '11/11/1971', '1234567890', 'Sector-85, Gurgaon', '28.404634', '76.950958', '', 'Haryana', '', 'demo@gmailx.com', 'profile20171123125011.png', 'document20171123125011.png', 'Upto 12th Class', 'B.Tech. MBA', '', '394,395,396,203', 'Expertise in program management.', '1', '09:00:00', '08:00 PM'),
```

tbl_skills Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_skills` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `skill_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
INSERT INTO `tbl_skills` (`id`, `skill_name`, `user`) VALUES
(202, 'Project Management, Delivery Management,Release', 111)
```

Comment: 1. You didn't specify your DB schema, nor did you provide any sqlfiddle.
2. You didn't provide any data from your DB, so how can anyone know the data your SQL runs with?

Comment: Stop. See normalisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for the numbers individually within the CSV string as follows:

```
SELECT *, (6371 * acos (
        cos ( radians('28.4594965') )
        * cos( radians( latitude ) )
        * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('77.0266383') )
        + sin ( radians('28.4594965') )
        * sin( radians( latitude )
))) AS distance
FROM tbl_serviceprovider
WHERE LOCATE(',202,', CONCAT(',', skills, ','))
    OR LOCATE(',395,', CONCAT(',', skills, ','))
ORDER BY distance;
```

By surrounding both values with commas and using `LOCATE` this will ensure the actual value is found.  This needs each where clause `OR`ed together as each `skill_id` searched for needs it's own clause.  It's not that elegant but it is simple and will work.

I also echo others view that this should be normalised, storing the CSV of skills in a string isn't the best solution.

Comment: downvote? why does this not work? I didn't decide to store the data in a csv string I'm only trying to answer the question.  Please indicate what is wrong if you downvote.

Comment: the solution seems legit to me, the LOCATE + CONCAT should do the job